# Are these norms equivalent in the product space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $p_1, p_2\geq 1$. Consider the product space $W:=W_0^{1, p_1}(\Omega)\times W_0^{1, p_2}(\Omega)$ equipped with the norm
$$\Vert (u, v)\Vert_W = \Vert u\Vert_{W_0^{1, p_1}} + \Vert v\Vert_{W_0^{1, p_2}} \quad \mbox{ for all } (u, v)\in W.$$
My question is the following one. If I consider the norm given by

$$\left(\Vert u\Vert_{W_0{1, p_1}}^{\max(p_1, p_2)} + \Vert v\Vert_{W_0{1, p_2}}^{\max(p_1, p_2)}\right)^{\frac{1}{\max(p_1, p_2)}},$$

it is equivalent to the norm defined above? And what about if I replace $\max(p_1, p_2)$ with $\min(p_1, p_2)$? The equivalence is also preserved?

Could anyone please help or give some references? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All norms on a product $X \times Y$ that have the form
$$\lVert (x,y)\rVert = N(\lVert x\rVert_X, \lVert y\rVert_Y)$$
where $N \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a norm are equivalent. This easily follows from the equivalence of all norms on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The analogous result holds for products of an arbitrary finite number of normed spaces. All norms of the form
$$N(\lVert x_1\rVert_{X_1}, \dotsc, \lVert x_n\rVert_{X_n})$$
where $N$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent.

Comment: So, are you saying that the answer is yes?

Comment: Yes. The norms you consider are of that form. With $N$ being the $\ell^1$-norm, the $\ell^{\max (p_1,p_2)}$-norm and the $\ell^{\min (p_1,p_2)}$-norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ respectively.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is also understood that doesn’t matter if I take the maximum between $p_1$ and $p_2$? I mean, if I consider $$ \left(\Vert u\Vert_{W_0^{1, p_1}}^{\max(\alpha, \beta)} + \Vert v\Vert_{W_0^{1, p_2}}^{\max(\alpha, \beta)}\right)^{\frac{1}{\max(\alpha, \beta)}}$$ for $\alpha, \beta >1$ real numbers, it is also equivalent?

Comment: That's a norm of the same type, hence equivalent too. All norms $$\lVert (x,y)\rVert = \bigl(\lVert x\rVert_X^q + \lVert y\rVert_Y^q\bigr)^{1/q}, \quad 1 \leqslant q < +\infty$$ and also $\lVert (x,y)\rVert = \max (\lVert x\rVert_X, \lVert y\rVert_Y)$ are equivalent (and a load of other norms too, but the $\ell^q$-norms for $q \in [1,+\infty]$ are the typically used norms).